# Get contents of an online file and assign it to a variable

Tags: java

How do I retrieve the contents of a file and assign it to a string?

The file is located on a https server and the content is plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer I found:

```
public static String readPage(String url, String delimeter)
{
    try
    {
        URL URL = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = URL.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line, lines = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if(lines != "")
            {
                lines += delimeter;
            }
            lines += line;
        }
        return lines;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/): easy, clean code and it handles the character encoding sent by the server -- something that `java.net.URL`/`java.net.URLConnection` force you to handle yourself:

```
String url = "http://example.com/file.txt";

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet(url));
String contents = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without this include?

Comment: Yes, but it's going to be a lot of code that has already been written, tested and proved itself elsewhere. I wouldn't recommend to write something like this from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [URL Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) in the Java API.

Pretty sure all you need is there.

Answer (score 0):

First download the file from the server using the `URL` class of java.

```
String url = "http://url";
java.io.BufferedInputStream in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(new 
java.net.URL(url).openStream());
java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream("file.txt");
java.io.BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,1024);
byte data[] = new byte[1024];
while(in.read(data,0,1024)>=0)
{
   bout.write(data);
}
bout.close();
in.close();
```

Then read the downloaded file using `FileInputStream` class of java

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
int ch;
StringBuffer strContent = new StringBuffer("");
FileInputStream fin = null;
try {
fin = new FileInputStream(file);
while ((ch = fin.read()) != -1)
strContent.append((char) ch);
fin.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e);
}
System.out.println(strContent.toString());
```

Comment: Why download into a file first? Also, the file-to-string conversion is questionable: `StringBuffer` (vs. `StringBuilder`), unbuffered single-char reading, and leaks a file handle on exception -- and this will break horribly on multi-byte Unicode characters.

Comment: Can you discuss more on file-to-string questionability.?

Comment: Most methods of `StringBuffer` synchronize internally which is unnecessary here, `StringBuilder` doesn't. Reading individual chars (or anything really) is very slow -- wrapping the `FileInputStream` into `BufferedInputStream` and then `BufferedReader` would increase the speed a lot. `BufferedReader` would also take care of any multi-byte Unicode characters. Also, the `fin.close()` should be in a finally block so the stream gets always closed -- as it is, it fails to close when `fin.read()` throws. I would usually use some library to convert a stream to string instead of writing my own.

Comment: The [implementation of `EntityUtils.toString()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1.3/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.java#171) does a good job at converting an `InputStream` to a `String` (they use their own `CharArrayBuffer`, similar to `StringBuilder`).

Comment: If you really want something handwritten, have a look at this: http://pastebin.com/RyfF9snB -- I implemented all the advice I've given above. Still, I strongly suggest to use a tested library for this.